# Picard-Lindelöf Theorem

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

This is a multipart problem, and I will paste all relevant information below:
[image]

[image]

[image]

I believe I have shown (i)-(iv), but I am stuck on the last two. Can anyone help me? I am quite confused. Thanks!

Edit: I'm really trying to figure out (v) and (vi), but I a quite stuck. I do not know how to show that $U$ is closed, and then am confused about the notation he expects for Banach's Fixed point theorem. Further, the last question, to show uniqueness, I have no guesses on. Can someone please help me? Thanks

Comment: Just for curiosity, what is the name of this book?

Comment: @Lemur We don't use a book. My professor types up our problem sets. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you have a strict contraction $T$, it can have at most one fixed point. Indeed, if $y$ and $\tilde{y}$ are two fixed points of $T$, then
$$ \|y-\tilde{y}\| = \|T(y)-T(\tilde{y})\|
 \leq L \|y-\tilde{y}\|,$$
and you conclude that $y=\tilde{y}$ because $L<1$.

For the closedness of $U$, here is a hint: pick a sequence $\{y_n\}_n$ from $U$, and assume that $y_n \to y$ uniformly in $[-\delta,\delta]$. Then you must prove that the range of $y$ is contained in $R$ and that $y$ is continuous on $[-\delta,\delta]$. The second thing should be clear to you (uniform convergence preserves continuity), while the first follows from the fact that $R$ is closed and the fact that uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence.